# Build a df based on another df which only has 1/0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which only has 1/0. I want to build a df with the same shape.
I want to consider the first two 1 in the case which we have consecutive 1.
For example, in a case we have 0,0,1,1,1,1, 0,0 I want to convert it to 0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0. Here is an example,

```
import pandas as pd

df_dr = pd.DataFrame()
df_dr['0'] = [0,0]
df_dr['1'] = [1,0]
df_dr['2'] = [1,1]
df_dr['3'] = [1,1]
df_dr['4'] = [0,1]
df_dr['5'] = [1,0]
df_dr['6'] = [1,0]
df_dr['7'] = [1,0]
df_dr['8'] = [1,1]
df_dr['9'] = [0,1]
df_dr['10'] = [0,1]
df_dr['11'] = [0,1]
df_dr['12'] = [0,1]
```

and here is the output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
```

Could you please help me with that? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? That is, what do you need help with exactly? for example, are you familiar with [consecutive grouping techniques](/q/32683492/4518341 "Make Pandas groupby act similarly to itertools groupby")? Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips like how to write a good title. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: BTW, that's an overly verbose way to build a df. Just use a dict, `DataFrame({'0': [0, 0], ...})`

Comment: it seems like you're wanting `df_dr[df_dr.cumsum(1).gt(2)] = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try something like this:

```
df_dr.eq(0).cumsum(1).T.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x).cumcount().isin([1,2])).astype(int).T
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   0   0
```

Method 2:

```
df_dr.eq(0).cumsum(1).apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x).cumcount(), axis=1).isin([1,2]).astype(int)
```